# Where to put server address where data will store?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating an app that capture video and upload it to server i have create the code for capture video ,and for upload I am studying [this code](https://github.com/chetanbhalala) but I did not understand to where to put my server address to store data there.

And also is there posible to store video using FTP because in my company PHP and .NET guys use FTP and i want to know that i am able to upload video using FTP in my iPhone app.

Comment: in the [WebService.m](https://github.com/chetanbhalala/FIle-upload-on-server-using-iOS/blob/master/FileUploadDownload/FileUploadDownload/WebService/WebService.m) file, there's a placeholder that says "your URL string", replace that.

Comment: any guidance on using FTP @H2Co3

Comment: I made this an answer, and also added some info about FTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [WebService.m](https://github.com/chetanbhalala/FIle-upload-on-server-using-iOS/blob/master/FileUploadDownload/FileUploadDownload/WebService/WebService.m) file, there's a placeholder that says "your URL string", replace that with your actual server.

If you want to use FTP, you can do that as well using a networking library that supports FTP, one in particular is the very popular [libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) library.